# Como manejar carga de catálogos en Formulario reactivo en Angular?

Tags: angular, angular6, observable

estoy dando vueltas a un asunto de carga de catálogos en un formulario reactivo porque no encuentro la manera de recuperar el elemento del catálogo que fué almacenado en base de datos para mostrarlo al cliente en un control de lista. Lo que hago es filtrar de un archivo json ese elemento que quiero mostrar, pero el comportamiento nunca llena mi array a la primera(osea hasta que recargo mi aplicación llena mi variable ProductoFake[] ).
De entrada cargo todo el catalogo porque el mismo Formulario que guarda sirve para editar

```
 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private eventoService: EventosService, private router: Router, public activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,private http:HttpClient) {
    
    this.http.get("../assets/data/fakeRepo.json").subscribe(repo=>{
      let products=JSON.stringify(repo);
       this.sportsData=JSON.parse(products);       
    });
    eventoService.zonasEvento().subscribe(lista => this.zonasEvento = lista);
    
  }
```

Utilizo el ActivatedRoute para diferenciar el modo del formulario

```
public sportsData: ProductoFake[]=[];
  
  public repoSelected:ProductoFake[]=[];
  private _producto:ProductoFake={Id:'',Game:''};
ngOnInit() {
this.frmG = this.fb.group({
      fechaInicio: '',
      fechaFin: '',
      duracion: '',
      nombreevento: '',
      noAsistentes: '',
      productospromocionar: ''
    });
    console.log('1.-Origen sportData');
    console.log(this.sportsData);
    this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(param => {
      if (param['id'] == null) {
        return;
      } else {
        //llamr a servicio obtenerEvento
        this.modoVer = true;
        console.log('1)getEvento encontró id');
        this.eventoService.getEvento(param['id']).subscribe(event =>          
          this.cargaData(event,event.productospromocionar)
        );
      }

    });
```

Tuve que utilizar un mock de observable para que se ejecutara mi funciones en modo secuencial

```
    cargaData(mievento: EventoT,clavesprod:string[]){
     let url="../assets/data/fakeRepo.json";          
   var repoSelected=this.repoSelected;// this.repoSelected es una variable global
    var sportsData=this.sportsData;// pero para accederla desde función la asigno en otra var
    console.log('2)deberería llenar sportsData local,pero no lo hace'); 
function mockHTTPRequest(url) {
      return Observable.of(`Response from ${url}`)
        //.delay(300);
    }
function recuperaRepo(arreglo: string[]): boolean{   
      console.log('4)'+sportsData[0]);
      var ind=0;
      arreglo.forEach(element => {
 let productoFake=sportsData.filter(x=>x.Id==element)[ind];        
          _producto.Id=productoFake.Id;
          //alert('elem[ind].nombre'+_producto.Game);
          _producto.Game=productoFake.Game;        
          repoSelected.push(_producto);
          ind=ind+1;
});
return true;
}
   function cargaFormulario(mievent: EventoT) {
let products=JSON.stringify(repoSelected);
      
      sportsData=JSON.parse(products);
}
      Observable.of(url)
      .concatMap(_url=>{
        console.log('3)ejecutando Observable recupeRepo');
        recuperaRepo(clavesprod);
        //this.sportsData = repoSelected;
        console.log("5)podría asignar repoSelected");
        return mockHTTPRequest(_url);
      })
      .do(response=> {console.log(response);
       cargaFormulario(mievento)})
       .subscribe(response => {
         //alert('pasó cargaFormulario, enseguida llenará campos:'+mievento.noAsistentes);
         this.sportsData = repoSelected;//sportsData    cuando es un array de un solo producto llega a funcionar;
         console.log("6)asignó " + repoSelected[0]);

        this.frmG.patchValue({
          fechaInicio:mievento.dateIni,
          fechaFin: mievento.dateFin,
          duracion: mievento.duracion,
          nombreevento: mievento.nombreevento,
          noAsistentes: mievento.asistentes,
          productospromocionar: this.repoSelected//sportsData <- ponga var local o global(this.repoSelected) hace lo mismo
        })
       }
        );
}
```